# Способ хранения координат фишек

Tags: c++, массивы, visual-c++, динамические-массивы

Пишу бота, который будет играть в простейшую игру. В начале каждого хода из файла считывается игровое поле, которое представляет собой матрицу 8х8. В игре 4 игрока, их фишки, соответственно, обозначены цифрами 1, 2, 3, 4 и расставлены на игровом поле. Нужно найти все фишки каждого игрока и каким-то образом хранить местоположение (координаты) каждой фишки. Как можно это сделать? Пробовал запоминать координаты в обычный массив и в `vector`, но это не совсем удобно.

Comment: Что именно вы хотите добиться? Как можно меньше места, как можно более быстрая операция (какая?), что-то иное?

Comment: Когда найдены все фишки игрока, то выбирается случайная из них и ходит случайным образом. Необходимо, чтобы можно было максимально просто получить доступ к координатам выбранной фишки.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Есть два варианта хранения - хранение состояния игры (доски), а на ней фишек (например, массив

```
int board[8][8];
```

в котором пустые поля обозначены нулями, а непустые - номером стоящей там фишки.

Но исходя из *"Необходимо, чтобы можно было максимально просто получить доступ к координатам выбранной фишки"*, вам нужен второй вариант - а именно, массив фишек с их координатами (x,y), которые можно реализовать как стандартный `pair<int,int>`, а можно с помощью своей структуры типа

```
struct Point {
    int x,y;
};
```

Но, как я понимаю, вам нужно и то, и другое - чтобы, зная фишку, сразу получить возможные ходы - например, пустая ли какая-то клетка?

Я бы просто делал класс типа `Game`, который бы хранил и доску, и четыре фишки, и при каждом ходе обновлял как координаты фишки, так и состояние доски. Интерфейс такого класса содержал бы функции для
- возврата координат фишки номер `N`
- возврата номера фишки на поле (x,y) (0, если пусто)
- перемещения фишки `N` на новое поле.

Как бы вы ни старались, сделать этот класс медленным - с 64 полями - у вас не получится. Какое нужно внутреннее представление - смотрите сами, что вам привычнее.

Answer (score 4):

> Пробовал запоминать координаты в обычный массив и в vector, но это не совсем удобно.

А что неудобно? Если делать массив, то нужно конвертер в наглядную форму сделать. И будет всё очень даже удобно.

Но я бы взял пример из шахмат. Где одна ось буквами обозначается, другая цифрами.
Координаты записываются как A6, E3... и т.д. Это и очень быстрый вариант, и очень наглядный.